# Figuring out local port used with TypeORM

Tags: amazon-web-services, typeorm, ssh-tunnel

I am trying to create an SSH tunnel to access a MySQL DB in a VPC (the Aurora serverless variant) and have more or less followed an approach similar to what is described [here](https://medium.com/@michalisantoniou6/connect-to-an-aws-rds-using-an-ssh-tunnel-22f3bd597924). I've setup a jumpbox (an EC2 instance) and I can ssh just fine into it. However, I am struggling to get the local port forwarding to work as I cannot seem to figure out what local port my command uses. The SSH command I am using is similar to this:

```
ssh -N -L ssh_localPort:rdsHost:rds_remotePort user@remoteHost -i ~/path/to/key
```

I use [typeORM](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm) to create and run DB migration scripts with a command taking the following form:

```
ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js migration:run -c database_name
```

The configuration for that DB looks something like this:

```
{
    "name": "database_name",
    "type": "mysql",
    "host": "host_name",
    "port": 3306,
    "username": "user",
    "password": "password",
    "database": "database_name",
    "entities": ["models/database_name/*.*"],
    "migrationsTableName": "migration",
    "migrations": ["migration/database_name/*.ts"],
    "cli": {
        "migrationsDir": "migration/database_name"
    }
}
```

I feel like I have all the pieces except for the local port. TypeOrm sets the port used to communicate with the DB so I was assuming that a port could be explicitly set via ts-node but could not find an option that would allow that.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to retrieve the local port or set it explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was being somewhat dense when working through this and didn't recognize two things:

1. The traffic from the localhost will be forwarded to the jumpbox on the specified port
2. The local port is set in the DB config file

I updated the config file to the following:

```
{
    ...
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": ssh_local_port,
    "username": "rds_user",
    "password": "rds_password",
    ...
}
```

and that was enough for me to connect remotely!